# How to quickly cut up and reassemble a C# List?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

The setup:
I have a session variable that carries a list of IDs, pipe-delimited. The IDs are related to views in my site, and related to a breadcrumb builder.

```
Session["breadCrumb"] = "1001|1002|1003|1004";
```

If I'm on the view that corresponds to 1002, I'd like to cut everything AFTER that id out of the session variable.

I'd thought to use something like:

```
var curView = "1002";

if (Session["breadCrumb"] != null) {
    var crumb = Session["breadCrumb"].ToString().Split('|').ToList();
    var viewExists = crumb.Any(c => c.Value == curView);

    if (viewExists) {
        //remove everything after that item in the array.
    }

}
```

But I'm wide open to methodologies.

Comment: why not split on curView, then split on your delimiter? (only taking the 0th element of the split result)

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni: Because what happens if `curView` was just `"1"`?

Comment: I'm accepting OP's example as contextual and sufficient to identify likely ranges. My FIRST instinct would be to not store a list of ints as a pipe delimited list, after all....

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni: Mine too. But why make unforced assumptions?

Comment: I'm entirely open to other methodology. I must admit I'm not sure how to store/access lists in/from sessions.

Comment: There is any possibility that the breadcrumb doesn't contain the curView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just store a `List<string>` in the `Session` [directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1259942/11963). This saves you from having to split/concat the string manually. I know this does not answer the question directly, but I believe it is a superior solution to that.

```
var curView = "1002";

var crumb = Session["breadCrumb"] as List<string>;
if (crumb != null) {
    var viewExists = crumb.Any(c => c.Value == curView);

    if (viewExists) {
        // remove everything after that item in the array.            
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like this approach, but the `//remove everything after that item in the array` is also a sticking point for me. How do I go about cutting out everything after curView from the list?

Comment: Actually, I've answered that sub-question myself. I set up a new list, and iterate through the existing one, filling the new list up to and including the current view, at which point I stop making the new list, and set the session equal to that list.

Comment: Using the approach of putting my list directly into the session, and skipping the whole "delimited string" thing was just the ticket. I figured out the rebuilding of the list up to the current item, and moved on from there. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You could use [TakeWhile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534804(v=vs.100).aspx) to get back only the items from the splitted list that precede the currentView.

```
var curView = "1002";
if (Session["breadCrumb"] != null) 
{
    var crumb = Session["breadCrumb"].ToString().Split('|').ToList();
    var viewExists = crumb.TakeWhile(c => c != curView).ToList();
    viewExists.Add(curView);
    string result = string.Join("|",viewExists);
}
```

While this approach works I think that also the previous answer (now wrongly deleted from Mr. Andrew Whitaker) was correct. Using IndexOf should be faster with less splitting, looping, joining strings. I suggest Mr Whitaker to undelete its answer.

**EDIT**
**This is from the deleted answer from [Mr.Whitaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497356/andrew-whitaker).**
I will repost here because I think that its approach is simpler and should give better perfomances, so future readers could see also this option.

```
var crumb = Session["breadCrumb"].ToString()
int index = crumb.IndexOf(curView);
if (index >= 0)
{
    Session["breadCrumb"] = crumb.Substring(0, index + curView.Length);
}
```

If Andrew decide to undelete its answer I will be glad to remove this part. Just let me know.

Comment: In this instance, `c.Value` was just me psuedo-coding. :)

Comment: Goodness, Mr.Whitaker's answer really would be incredibly fast: No .Split('|) and no .ToList() would really speed things up. Still, your answer is quite useful for demonstrating where .TakeWhile() can be used (at least I found it useful!).

Answer (score 1):

I almost regret this, but frankly I'd just go for a regular expression:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=(\\||^)" + current + ")(?=\\||$).*", "");
```

This does not directly tell you if the current view existed in the input, but even though this is also possible with the regex in this particular instance another, dead simple test exists:

```
var viewExists = result.Length != current.Length;
```

Comment: It seems there is at least one person here who really dislikes regexes. I wonder why.

Comment: I havent't tried @Jon's code, but RegEx comes before code search. Harder to write but faster and keep the performance up even with bigger data.

Comment: I'm not sure why there was a downvote on it. I like the approach, because I'm a fan of regex, but in the end I wound up going with lists in sessions. Actually, I went with a list of tuples.