# How to store a list in client side in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page that includes a wizard with 3 step.

step 1 is nothing that matter.

but in step 2 I have some fields that I want to add their value in a class named `Stages`. In page load I call a list of `Stages` like this: `List<Stages> temp = new List<Stages>;`

If the user clicks 'save_btn' I add fields of step2 in a `Stages item` and add this item in the `temp (list)`.  That works fine.

But after that click I want to stay in step 2 and refill the fields and add another item if user wants. But its not working. The `temp` list is set to null after that click. I don't know how tell asp to not renew the list. I tried `if (!IsPostBack)` but still not working.

```
List<Stages> temp;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        temp = new List<Stages>();
}
protected void save_stage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stages stg = new Stages()
    {
        description_1 = stage_description_1.Text,
        description_2 = stage_description_2.Text,
        description_3 = stage_description_3.Text,
        description_4 = stage_description_4.Text,
    };
    temp.Add(stg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use session:

```
Session["stg"] = stg;

var list = (List<Stages>)Session["stg"];
```

[Store List to session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259934/store-list-to-session)

Comment: very helpfull link. thanx