# Can I make a Session variable that behaves like a vector/list?

Tags: c#, session-variables

So, I'm using C# and I really need to store in a Session variable multiple data. I can't define as many Session variables as I need because I the number could be infinite.

I need to store everything in a Session, then loop through it. Is it possible?

So: I have a page with products, the Client can ADD to the basket as many items as he wants (all of this occurrs on the same page).

Comment: What is the problem when you add a list (or array) to your session?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store List to session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259934/store-list-to-session)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over all keys or store a list of elements using one key "basket" (or "cart"):

```
IList<CartItem> GetCartLines()
{
    return Session["Basket"] as List<CartItem>;
}

void AddToCart(CartItem item)
{
    var cartLines = Session["Basket"] as List<CartItem>;
    if(cartLines==null)
        Session["Basket"] = cartLines = new List<CartItem>();
    cartLines.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the if statement be (cartLines == null)?
This has helped me, thanks!

It's just strange seeing how the Session Object gets bigger by just using Add over cartLines (which is implicitly the Session Object)